# Verifying continuity of multiplication

Tags: calculus

Verify that $|ab-a_0 b_0 |\le|a||b-b_0 |+|b_0 ||a-a_0 |$, for all real numbers $a$, $a_0$, $b$ and $b_0$.

I know how to prove this through rectangles, but I'm confused about how to go over this algebrically.

Comment: Hint: add a zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|ab-a_0b_0| = |ab-ab_0+ab_0-a_0b_0|\leq |ab-ab_0|+|ab_0-a_0b_0|=|a||b-b_0|+|b_0||a-a_0|$$

Comment: That made sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can also have the result this way.

$\begin{cases}
a=a_0+h\\
b=b_0+k\end{cases}\quad$ with $(h,k)\to (0,0)$

$ab=(a_0+h)(b_0+k)=a_0b_0+\underbrace{a_0k+b_0h+hk}_{\to 0}\to a_0b_0$

In the formula you proposed above $|a||b-b_0|$ still has a term $|a|$ that is variable. It would be preferable to bound the result by the product of a constant $|a_0|$ by a term that goes to zero $|b-b_0|$.

So instead, let's write it to make the second order term appear explicitely, so that the developpement around $(a_0,b_0)$ is more obvious.

$|ab-a_0b_0|=|a_0k+b_0h+hk|\le\underbrace{|a_0||b-b_0|}_\text{first order term}+\underbrace{|b_0||a-a_0|}_\text{first order term}+\underbrace{|a-a_0||b-b_0|}_\text{second order term}$

Comment: This is really great. Thank you.