# Product of two real numbers is a continuous topological map

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I wish to prove that the map $ f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$ f(x, y) = xy$$

(that is, simply, the product of two real numbers), is continuous.

By the definition of continuous map, one must show that the inverse image of every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open. It is sufficient to prove it for open intervals $(a, b)$ since they form a basis. Now:

$$f^{-1} (a,b) = \{(x,y) : xy>a  \} \cap \{(x,y) : xy<b \}$$

and thus it is enough to show that the first of these is open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ (the other one will similarly be open, and the intersection of two open sets will be open). I shall denote it $A = \{(x,y) : xy>a  \}$, and the other relevant set $B = \{(x,y) : xy=a  \}$

Now, to show it is open, since we have the metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is sufficient to show that for every point $(x, y) \in A$ there is a ball centered around it contained in $A$.

Thinking graphically, I would let:

$\varepsilon = \inf \{d((x,y), (x', y'))  , (x', y') \in B\}$

(that is, the infimum of the distances to every point in the set $B$), which would then make the ball centered around $(x,y)$ with radius $\varepsilon$ contained in $A$ and thus make $A$ open.

However, since $B$ is not shown to be closed, as far as this proof goes, $\varepsilon$ is not shown to be positive: it could be that $(x, y)$ lies in the closure of $B$ and thus its distance would be $0$. I know this is not the case, but the reasoning seems circular. What would be a formal way of finding a ball contained in $A$ without needing to show that $B$ is closed? (Of course one could not see that $B$ is closed since it is the inverse inverse image of a continuous map by a single point, since to see that $xy$ is a continuous function one has to proof the very hypothesis of my question, which would again be circular reasoning)

Comment: The algebra you need is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230107/verifying-continuity-of-multiplication

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following, although my way is very different from what you tried.

Since we are in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, we know that this topological spaces are also metric spaces, with the metric given by the euclidean distance. In metric spaces we have the following characterization for continuity:

**Proposition.** Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(Y,d_2)$ be two metric spaces and $f: X \to Y$ a function. Then $f$ is continuous in a point $x_0 \in X$ if and only if, for every sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$, such that $a_n \to x_0$, we have that the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is such that $f(a_n) \to f(x_0)$.

So with this proposition is very straight forward. Let $x_0 = (y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, suppose you have a sequence $(a_n,b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(a_n,b_n) \to (y_1,y_2)$, this implies that $a_n \to y_1$ and $b_n \to y_n$. Can you finish the proof?

Maybe you want the procedure using only topological properties without using metrics, but as you can see, metric properties make our lives easier.

Answer (score 0):

The sets $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, b)$ form a subbasis for the topology on $\mathbb R$, thus you correctly state that it suffices to show that $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ and $f^{-1}((-\infty, b))$ are open.

However, this is no advantage and we shall consider the sets $f^{-1}((a,b))$.

You also correctly say

> Now, to show $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is open, since we have the metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is sufficient to show that for every point $(x_0, y_0) \in f^{-1}((a,b))$ there is a ball centered around it  contained in $f^{-1}((a,b))$.

But it is more convenient to find open intervals $U_0$ containing $x_0$ and $V_0$ containing $y_0$ such that $U_0 \times V_0  \subset f^{-1}((a,b))$. Clearly $U_0 \times V_0$ contains an open ball centered around $(x_0, y_0)$.

Let $p_0 = x_0y_0$. Pick $d > 0$ such that $(p_0-d,p_0+d) \subset (a,b)$. If $x_0 = y_0 = 0$, define $r =  \sqrt{\frac d 2}$, otherwise $r = \min\left(\sqrt{\frac d 2}, \frac{d}{2(\lvert x_0 \rvert + \lvert y_0 \rvert)}\right)$. In both cases $r^2 \le  \frac d 2$ and $(\lvert  x_0 \rvert + \lvert y_0 \rvert) r \le \frac d 2$.

We claim that $(x_0 - r, x_0 + r) \times (y_0 - r, y_0 + r) \subset f^{-1}((a,b))$.

Let $x = x_0 + u$ with $\lvert u \rvert < r$ and $y = y_0 + v$ with $\lvert v \rvert < r$. Then $xy = x_0y_0 + x_0v + y_0u + uv$ and therefore
$$\lvert xy - x_0y_0 \rvert = \lvert  x_0v + y_0u + uv \rvert \le \lvert  x_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert  v \rvert + \lvert  y_0 \rvert \cdot \lvert  u \rvert + \lvert  u \rvert \cdot \lvert  v \rvert < \lvert  x_0 \rvert r + \lvert y_0 \rvert r + r^2 \\ = (\lvert  x_0 \rvert + \lvert y_0 \rvert) r + r^2 \le \frac d 2  + \frac d 2 = d .$$

The definition of $r$ seems to be a bit tricky at first glance, but it is quite obvious since we want to achieve $(\lvert  x_0 \rvert + \lvert y_0 \rvert) r + r^2 \le d$.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the simplicity of this case, in constrast to the general case, I will answer the related question where we only consider positive reals.

Write $\mathbb{P}=(0,\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $g:\mathbb{P}\times \mathbb{P}\to \mathbb{P}$ be the multiplication, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.

**Claim.**
$g$ is continuous.

*Proof.*

As stated above, it suffices to show that $g^{-1}((a,b))$ is open. Like Paul Frost, I will show that it is covered by rectangular opens $I\times J$ where $I,J$ are open intervals. Let $(x_0,y_0)\in g^{-1}((a,b))$. Take
\begin{align*}
I&=\left(\sqrt{\frac{ax_0}{y_0}},\sqrt{\frac{bx_0}{y_0}}\right)\\
J&=\left(\sqrt{\frac{ay_0}{x_0}},\sqrt{\frac{by_0}{x_0}}\right)
\end{align*}

We need to show that $(x_0,y_0)\in I\times J\subset g^{-1}((a,b))$. Well, as $(x_0,y_0)\in g^{-1}((a,b))$,
\begin{align*}
a&\le x_0y_0\le b\\
\implies \sqrt{\frac{ax_0}{y_0}}&\le y_0\le \sqrt{\frac{bx_0}{y_0}}\\
\implies \sqrt{\frac{ay_0}{x_0}}&\le x_0\le \sqrt{\frac{by_0}{x_0}}\\
\implies (x_0,y_0)&\in I\times J
\end{align*}
Also, for $(x,y)\in I\times J$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{ax_0}{y_0}}&\le y\le \sqrt{\frac{bx_0}{y_0}}\\
\sqrt{\frac{ay_0}{x_0}}&\le x\le \sqrt{\frac{by_0}{x_0}}\\
\implies a&\le xy\le b\\
\implies (x,y)&\in g^{-1}((a,b))\\
\end{align*}
$\square$

*Remark.*
This case is simpler as for positive reals, $x<u$ and $y<v$ implies $xy<uv$.